# Error while testing NodeJS and MongoDB stack using Mocha and Chai

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mocha.js

Right now, I'm running Mocha tests and am getting the following error:

```
  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1077:14)
```

I assume it's because I am unable to connect to port 27017 because I did not include:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
```

However, what is particularly confusing to me is how I connect by test to MongoDB so I can create fake records for testing and then destroy them. If anyone can show me (with an example please) how to do it, that would be awesome!

Thanks again.

Comment: Are you running mongodb? Is it running on same port 27017?

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming may be the mongo server is not running or from more than one server trying to listen on same port. Also for test environment only can create different folder or use different port. So that can delete the folder once test case is over

In server.js

```
if(process.env === 'test')
{
    mongoport = 57017;
}
else
{
    mongoport = 27017;
}
mongoUrl = "mongodb://localhost:"+mongoport+"/student"
// use the mongodb url
```

In test.js

```
//on start of test case

var fs = require('fs-extra');
fs.removeSync("test/db/");
fs.ensureDirSync("test/db/");
//ur test case definition
```